# Spring Boot - Order among Auto Configurations classes of third party libraries

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am facing an issue in a spring boot project, where if auto configuration of `Lib A` runs before `Lib B` I get unexpected results. I would like to run auto configuration of these libs in a predefined order. Can someone please help me out.

These libs are external, and I have no control over it. So I can't use `@Order`, `@AutoConfigureAfter`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try with this `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)`
or

`@Order(1)`

`@Order(2)`

In different configurations

Comment: I can't modify the classes, they are third party.